# Add items to the ObservableCollection from threads other than the UI thread in Avalonia

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, avalonia

I have little problem with ObservableCollection , when I want to add an Element to the Collection , from another Thread , i have a problem with refreshing my ListBox.

```
if (GeneralInformation.FilterRecieved)
{

        MainWindowViewModel.FramePreviewViewModel.AddFrame(FrameToDecode, DateTime.Now.Ticks); 
        MainWindowViewModel.FramePreviewViewModel.OnPropertyChanged("FilteredFrames");
        Console.WriteLine(MainWindowViewModel.FramePreviewViewModel.FilteredFrames.Count);
}
```

```
  public void AddFrame(CANFrame frame , long timeStamp)
  {

      string frameToString = frame.ToString();
      if (!RecievedFrames.ContainsKey(frame))
      {

          if ((frame.m_can_id & GeneralInformation.FilterCryterium) == frame.m_can_id)
          {
              FilteredFrames.Add(frameToString);
             Console.WriteLine("lalalal");   
          }
          RecievedFrames.Add(frame, timeStamp);
      }
      else
      {
          if ((frame.m_can_id & GeneralInformation.FilterCryterium) == frame.m_can_id)
          {
              FilteredFrames.Add(frameToString);
              Console.WriteLine("lalalal");
          }

          RecievedFrames[frame] = timeStamp;

      }

      if (RecievedFrames.Count == 20000)
              RecievedFrames.Remove(RecievedFrames.First().Key);
     
  }
```

I tried to use `NotifyPropertyChanged`  and `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Comment: Post your code as *text* in the question itself. Post enough code to reproduce the problem. In any case, you can't update the UI from another thread so *don't* try to modify the collection from another thread. Use `async/await` at the very least and modify the collection in the UI thread. To avoid flickering you can use `AddRange` or just replace one collection with another instead of adding items one by one

Comment: There's no multithreaded code in the question's snippet. If you ensure `AddFrame` is called in the UI thread, there won't be any problems. On the other hand, `RecievedFrames.Count == 20000` is suspicious. You can't display 20K items in a list box. You should probably use a `Queue` or `ConcurrentQueue` instead of an `ObservableCollection` and raise `NotifyPropertyChanged` explicitly after you modify the collection

Comment: You also claim to have tried use Dispatcher.Invoke, but no such code is shown. Do note that you need to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher`, or obtain a dispatcher object from the UI thread.